# Accessing a specific instance of an application installed on different machines behind a router (NAT), from the outside

Tags: networking, communication

**Question:**
Is there a way to safely reach an opened socket on a machine from the internet, knowing the routers external ip, the private network internal ip and the port, without having to explicitly configure the router and the firewall? Given that many machines on the private network run the targeted application and will only accept authentified and encrypted requests.

**Things I've explored:**

- Hole punching, ssh, proxy/vpn: They all seem like they need to configure the router to forward the port.
- UPnP: Would seem like the solution, but Google tells me it's been shown to be used by malicious softwares, so maybe not a long term solution?

**Context:**
I'm designing a system with a program (mini-server) that collects local data from the computer it is installed on and waits for a request from a known outside program (big-client), installed somewhere in the cloud, to send the collected data only when requested. I expect to have many of these mini-servers installed on many physical machines within a customer's private network, behind its router and firewall, where they would send to the big-client their external ip (internet exposed), local ip (on the local network) and port upon behind booted. These mini-servers can talk to each other on the network to resolve port conflicts and such, but I want to be able to dynamically add new ones without having to go back again in the router config, as this isn't scalable.

I understand the security necessity for this to be difficult to do, but when I think about software like Teamviewer and other remote desktop applications, they seem to be able to act on many machines behind a router without any conflict, and that upon request from the outside.

Comment: "_and that upon request from the outside._" No, the original connection comes from inside, and the outside can use that connection to send requests.

Comment: Thanks Ron! Is there a limitation to these type of solutions? I mean, at some point the connection must timeout. Or are they able to maintain a connection for each device worldwide?

Comment: You can have a keepalive (heartbeat) after creating the connection. Also, there will be multiple servers around the world (Google has a lot of `8.8.8.8` DNS servers, and you connect to the closest). There are also load balancers, etc. You really, really need to learn how networking works before trying something like this because that is how we end up with security holes.